# dim across multiple subs

Tags: vba, excel

I've a macro bound to a command button that allows users to insert an image.

```
    Sub Insert_Image()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .ButtonName = "Submit"
            .Title = "Select an image file"
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
            .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
            .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
            .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
            .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
            .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then
            Dim img As Object
            Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))

            'Position Image
            img.Left = 598
            img.Top = 70

mbResult = MsgBox("Did you select the correct image?", vbYesNo)

    Select Case mbResult
        Case vbNo:
            img.Delete
    End Select

        End If
    End With

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub


---------------------------------------------
Sub Delete_Image()

 img.Delete

End Sub
```

I'm trying to create a separate command button that'll allow the users to delete the image if they insert the wrong one.

When I change `Dim img As Object` to `Public img As Object` I get an Invalid Attribute in Sub or Function Error and if I leave it as `Dim` `img.delete` is empty.

I'm not sure how else to span variables across multiple subs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it outside your Sub, at the top of the module:

```
Option Explicit

Public img As Object

Public Sub CreateImg()
    Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteImg()
    If Not (img Is Nothing) Then
        img.Delete
        Set img = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That helped thank you, however `img.Delete` is giving the error `run-time error 1004` `Delete Method of picture class failed` now.

Comment: @L23P Hmm...  I don't know what Object Type `Sheet.Pictures.Insert` produces - I tend to prefer `Sheet.Shapes.AddPicture()`, to embed the image as a `Shape`.  You may need `img.Parent.Delete` - but save & back up before testing that!

Comment: @L23P Delete fails, because the first `Sub` protects the sheet. You have two options: Unprotect/Protect in DeleteImg or (a better solution) use `UserInterfaceOnly` parameter of [Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dpl-PL%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm175156)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue)